# Is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ a Dedekind domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian, dedekind-domain

Let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. So far I've shown that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is integrally closed (that is, the integral closure of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ with respect to its fraction field is itself) and $\dim\overline{\mathbb{Z}}=1$. However, as I don't really know how the ideals in $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ look like, I am at lost when thinking if $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is Noetherian or not.
Also, I would like to know for a non-trivial prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ what would the isomorphism class of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathfrak p$ be.

Comment: For the prime ideals : looking first at $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_\infty]$ is easier

Answer (score 6):

No. A Dedekind domain is necessarily Noetherian, but the ring of all algebraic integers
has strictly increasing chains of ideals, for instance, $(2)\subset (2^{1/2})\subset(2^{1/4})\subset\cdots$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea on what the isomorphism class would be for $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\beta$ for an ideal prime $\beta$? Or how could I work this out?

Comment: All the finitely generated ideals of $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}$ are inversible